Why two vectors in the same coset must have same distance to a lattice
I'm trying to understand the post-quantum cryptography standards released by NIST, which led me to learn about lattices. My knowledge of group theory isn't great but I followed along with the basics. However, something stumped me for a while.
In one tutorial it was stated as obvious that two vectors $\mathbf{r_1}$, $\mathbf{r_2}$ in the same coset (i.e. $\mathbf{t} + L$ where $\mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ and $L$ is a lattice on $\mathbb{Z}^m$) must necessarily have the same minimum distance to the lattice, but it took me a while to come up with a plausible seeming reason for this.
Say we have a lattice $L(\mathbf{A})$ where $\mathbf{r_1} = \mathbf{t} + \mathbf{As_1}$ and $\mathbf{r_2} = \mathbf{t} + \mathbf{As_2}$. Suppose $\mathbf{t}$ is closest to some other lattice point $\mathbf{As}$, so $\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{As} + \mathbf{e}$. Then $\mathbf{r_1} = \mathbf{As} + \mathbf{e} + \mathbf{As_1} = \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{s} + \mathbf{s_1}) + \mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{r_2} = \mathbf{As} + \mathbf{e} + \mathbf{As_2} = \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{s} + \mathbf{s_2}) + \mathbf{e}$. Then (this is where I'm unsure) if we can assume that when displaced by vector $\mathbf{e}$ from any lattice point we will still be closest to that same point, as is the case for $\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{As} + \mathbf{e}$, then $||\mathbf{e}||$ would be the minimum distance for both $\mathbf{r_1}$ and $\mathbf{r_2}$. I guess this could be proven by the symmetry of the lattice?
Am I understanding this correctly or am I totally off base? I'd appreciate any help.

Draw a few cosets in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. This should make it clear.

@CyclotomicField Thank you, it did help with visualizing the situation intuitively

Your way of thinking is overly complicated.
The pair $r_1$ and $L$ is just a translation of $r_2-r_1$ away from the pair $r_2$ and $L$. Translations preserve distance.
Here’s a more rigorous approach for that intuition. If $r_1-r_2\in L$, then for any $e\in L$, note that $e-(r_1-r_2)\in L$. Therefore, $ ||r_1-e||=||r_2-(e-(r_1-r_2))||\geq d(r_2,L)$. Taking the minimum over all $e$ gives that $d(r_1,L)\geq d(r_2,L)$. Switching $r_1$ and $r_2$ gives the reverse, so the distances from $L$ are equal.

Thanks! That helped a lot
